# Why are my dependency Spring beans instantiated twice ? Once from the jar dependency and once from the classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the most puzzling Spring error message I ever had, well, I had a few over the years, but this one is one to remember.

The error message is:

```
Field orderService in com.thalasoft.butik.rest.config.FixtureService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - com.thalasoft.butik.data.service.OrderServiceImpl: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stephane/.m2/repository/com/thalasoft/butik-data/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/butik-data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/thalasoft/butik/data/service/OrderServiceImpl.class]
    - OrderService: defined by method 'OrderService' in class path resource [com/thalasoft/butik/data/config/JpaService.class]
```

The `butik` application is composed of 2 Spring projects, one being the `butik-data` project and the other one being the `butik-rest` project.

The error occurs when running the integration tests in the `butik-rest` project

```
mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2"
```

The very same error occurs when running the application and not running the integration tests:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

The dependency is only present once in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thalasoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>butik-data</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

My `butik-rest` project configuration looks like:

```
@EnvProd
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Component
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.butik.data" })
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}

@Component
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.exception",
    "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.controller", "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.assembler" })
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

The integration test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {
    "classpath:mysql/clean-up-before-each-test.sql" })
public abstract class BaseTest {

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.config",
    "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.butik.data" })
public class TestConfiguration {
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.butik.rest.filter" })
public class NoSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

The service beans are instantiated explicitly in the dependency project:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaService {

  @Bean
  public ProductServiceImpl ProductService() {
    return new ProductServiceImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public OrderServiceImpl OrderService() {
    return new OrderServiceImpl();
  }

}
```

Could it be that Spring gets one bean from the explicit instantiation above in the `butik-data` project, and another one from the `"com.thalasoft.butik.data"` scanning in the dependant `butik-rest` project ?

UPDATE: Even when changing the 2 instances of `"com.thalasoft.butik.data"` (there is one to run the application and another one to run the integration tests) into `"com.thalasoft.butik.data.config"` I still get the same error.

UPDATE: I see I had 2 mistakes compounding making the whole issue a bit tricky. I had to remove the `"com.thalasoft.butik.data.config"` instance from the integration tests also. And now the issue is gone.

Comment: Don't you have component scanning on the package `com.thalasoft.butik`? This would scan the whole classpath which includes your sources and libraries. If it finds two beans it will pick them up. That's a correct behavior.

Comment: May I ask what you suggest I should do ? How come the dependency classes are on the classpath ? I thought only the dependency jar is to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've scanned both of those locations. You need to investigate places which are currently scanned and which should be scanned.

If you think that current way of scanning (which include two beans which are suitable for autowiring 'orderService' field), you can mark one of those beans by annotation *@Primary* ( docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html ).

Bean marked by this annotation will be prefered over another ones, which should solve your problem.

Good luck :)

Comment: I have only one `orderService` bean and it is defined in the dependency `butik-data` project.

Comment: We need to taka a look on those two classes:
- com.thalasoft.butik.rest.config.FixtureService 
- com.thalasoft.butik.data.service.OrderServiceImpl (Does it have any annotation which add this to context as a another bean? )

So, please attach them to your post and take a look on them.
Please investigate also your autowiring settings - now it looks like it trys to auwiry by type, is it that what you are expecting?

Comment: I added an update to the question. I had two mistakes compounding in fact. I to removed the `"com.thalasoft.butik.data.config"` instance from the integration tests and now the issue is gone. Indeed, there was twice an inclusion of `"com.thalasoft.butik.data.config"`.